# Flutter cant to load asset

Tags: flutter

I cannot load my assets images and icons.
What can be the problem, i cant upgrade flutter version because its throw many errors if its supposed to be answer.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ImageIcon(
                  AssetImage("assets/icons/cash-back.png"),
                  color: Color(0xFF3A5A98),
                ),
                label: 'leagues',
                backgroundColor: AppColors.white,
              ),
```

[image]

error:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/icons/cash-back.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:227
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:673
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/icons/cash-back.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#c10e3(), name: "assets/icons/cash-back.png", scale: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include this in your pubspec.yaml file,

```
flutter:
  assets:
     - assets/
     - assets/icons/
```

For more check this link: [Adding assets and images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Comment: i had it but you are right the missing tab was the problem ):

Answer (score 2):

In your image, look at where you have specified the assets.

```
flutter:
#some comments
assets:
  - assets/
```

Notice how you have put "assets:" and "flutter:" on the same indentation. In pubspec.yaml, whitespace is important. Make sure that your indentation looks like this:

```
flutter:
#some comments
  assets:
    - assets/
```

The comments can make this mistake easy to miss, so make sure you pay very close attention to your indentation. Each child should be one tab or two spaces further indented than its parent.

Answer (score 1):

To include all assets under a directory, specify the directory name with the / character at the end and save all data in specific directory ( All images in images folder )

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/videos/
```

and run pub get

After pub get success you can refer your assets like

```
Image.asset(
 'assets/images/trash.png',
  scale: 1.8,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in your .yaml file**

```
flutter:
  assets:
    -android/assests/directory/
```